# How to disable or remove Gmail account from my Android

Tags: gmail

I don't want to receive email on my Android device, so how do I remove my Gmail account from it?

I realize that I need to have my Gmail account associated to the device, and that I would need to reset the phone to factory settings in order to remove this main account..

So do I have any options?

Comment: Quickest way I found for Android 2.3 was to reset to factory settings.

Answer (score 13):

Go to Settings->Accounts & Sync and touch your gmail account. It will show you options of what  you can sync (Books, Calendar, Contacts, Gmail, Music). Touch the Gmail one and it won't sync your gmail account with that device.

Comment: When I follow your steps Gmail does a sync.. these steps do not disable syncing, they initiate syncing.

Comment: Then syncing for gmail was already disabled.

Comment: Syncing was not disabled.. if you keep touching the Gmail button as you suggest doing then the account attempts to sync everytime. What version of Android are you using? I am on 2.2

Comment: I have 2.3 and 3.2 .. Maybe it's not possible with 2.2?

Comment: I believe this controls auto-sync, not sync during a Sync All operation.

Comment: For the record: I'm using 2.2, and when I go to Settings->Accounts & Sync and scroll down to my account under "Manager Accounts" and touch it, I get a control panel with several checkboxes for the sync settings for various Google services.  I personally have "Sync Gmail" unchecked, and this does prevent email from being downloaded...

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings > Accounts`. Click on your GMail account for sync on / off.  It will take you to the sync settings in emulator. Then, click account settings, it wil show your mail again. Now, click on your GMail account. It shows all your account details. On dragging down, you will see `remove your account` button. Click it; you will be safe now.

Comment: This works! With the difference that my 'Remove Account' was on the 3-dot overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root, you can delete the account database (/data/system/accounts.db) which will delete all accounts managed by system including Google accounts and those ones registered by a third-party app (Facebook, Twitter, Skype, etc.).

However, this method may cause the system to behave incorrectly sometimes. You also have to note you can't use stuff like the Market without a Google account.

Comment: I want to be able to use the Market still.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the account, I believe you can hit 'remove account' at the bottom after selecting the account to act upon in accounts/sync settings. De-selecting Gmail just means that it does not get auto-synchronized but is still affected by a 'sync all' operation.

Steps:

1. Select "Accounts"
2. Select "Google"
3. Select the account you want to remove.
4. Select "Remove account" below the "Sync now".

Comment: Won't work - you can't remove the account the phone was set up with without a factory reset.

Comment: Oh, nasty. I was able to… What form of Android are you on?

Comment: I tested it out on a fairly fresh install of Bugless Beast.

Comment: That's a custom ROM, so your experience and advice aren't going to match the average Android user's situation.

Comment: I had thought of it as very similar to stock, apologies if not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Access "System Settings" by touching soft key lower left on phone (3 horizontal lines).
2. under `Accounts`, touch "Google" this will bring up your Google/Gmail accounts.
3. click the account you wish to delete.
4. touch the soft key again (3 horizontal lines) this will open a window with two choices,
5. Click "remove account"

Answer (score -2):

If you're rooted, simply remove Gmail app using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) (free).

Or, better.. *freeze* Gmail app using [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) of Titanium Backup. This way, you can always get back Gmail easily in case you've changed your mind in future.